# Android Studio design preview not applying style?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a very simple `<style>` in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="roundActionButton">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_button_background</item>
</style>
```

I'm applying this style to a `FrameLayout` in one of my activities:

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/okButton"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/okButton"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
                style="@style/roundActionButton"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp">
```

The `FrameLayout` is visible, but the style is not applied in the Android Studio design preview, no matter how much I rebuild the project or force refresh the layout. However, if I set the background directly in the `FrameLayout`, it is displayed as expected in the design preview as well:

```
            <FrameLayout
                ...
                android:background="@drawable/action_button_background">
```

The theme in the design preview is set to AppTheme (I've tried others too but no change). Shouldn't the style be visible in the design preview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `android:` in style...

```
<style name="roundActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_button_background</item>
</style>
```